# Data Mapper: Is my interpretation correct?

Tags: oop, datamapper

I'm trying to confirm now, what I believe about the Data Mapper pattern. So here we go:

**Section A:**
A Data Mapper is a class which is used to create, update and delete objects of another Class. Example: A class called `Cat`, and a Data Mapper called `CatDataMapper`. And a database table called `cats`. But it could also be an xml file called `cats.xml`, or an hard-coded array called `cats`. The whole point of that Data Mapper is to free the Business Logic which uses the Cat class from thinking about "how to get an exisiting cat", or "how to save a cat", "where to save a cat". As a user of the Data Mapper it looks like a blackbox with well-defined methods like getCat(int id), saveCat(Cat catObject), deleteCat(Cat catObject), and so on.

**Section B:**
First I thought it would be clever if Cat inherits from CatDataMapper, because calling such functions then is a bit more convenient. For example, methods like catWithId(int id) could be static (class method) and return an instance of a Cat, initialized with data from *anywhere*. And when I work with a cat object in my code, I could simply call myCat->save(); to store it whereever the Data Mapper will store it (don't care where and how, the Data Mapper hides this complexity from the user).

In conclusion, I'm a little bit confused now ;) 
Do you think that **Section A** is valid for the Data Mapper pattern? And if I would do it additionaly as described in **Section B**, would that be bad? Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your **Section A** corresponds to the definiton of the Data Mapper pattern as given by [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html)

Be careful with the details of your implementation language.  In **Section B** having `catWithId()` be a static member of the `cat` class may interfere with polymorphic behavior of the method.

In java, the JVM will dispatch a static method based on the declared type of the reference.
Try this out:
1. create a class `CatDataMapper` with the static method `catWithId(int id)`
2. create a class `Cat` extending `CatDataMapper`  that has the desired Business Logic behavior
3. subclass `Cat` with `LoggedCat` that logs all activity, including the activity from `CatDataMapper`
4. do `Cat foo = new LoggedCat()`
5. do `Cat bar = foo.catWithId(5)`

note which method is called, it should be the static method of `CatDataMapper` not the static method of `LoggedCat`

http://faq.javaranch.com/view?OverridingVsHiding gives a more in-depth discussion of this.

Comment: Thanks. Please, can you explain what you mean with the last sentence "In Section B having catWithId() be a static member of the cat class may interfere with polymorphic behavior of the method."? What could go wrong when the cat class inherits this static method to create a new cat object with initialization based on a given id?

Comment: You just need to be aware of this edge case if you are implementing in Java. The `catWithId()` method is probably safe from this "gotcha" behavior.  Other methods that need polymorphic behavior would be problematic.  Don't forget about overriding methods for use in junit testing!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an OK approach.  Aside from the naming conventions used, you're following a well known Data Access pattern here and you're allowing the users of the Cat objects to perform CRUD operations without having to talk to the CatDataMapper which is always a plus in my book.

I would usggest looking at Spring Container technology for this if you're in the java world.